# GWT MenuItem-List selected value

Tags: java, gwt, menuitem

I have a bit of a problem. Like in the code I'm trying to create a dynamic MenuItem List. Which is no problem, but I want to have the item which is selected/clicked. But I'm not sure how to correctly implement that. all of this is happening in my View and i want to set the value to continue in the Presenter. thx for any help.

```
chooseProfileMenuBar = new MenuBar(true);
for (int i = 0; i<names().size(); i++) {

  final MenuItem menuItemChoose = new MenuItem(names.get(i), new Command(){

    @Override           
        public void execute() {

      // TODO set the onClicked value/name at index i               

    }
  });
  chooseProfileMenuBar.addItem(menuItemChoose);
}
return chooseProfileMenuBar;
```

Comment: if its any help. i'm setting the list from the presenter and also calling this method (creatingMenuItemList) from the presenter. Because i thing/thought is the correct concept approach. Or is it correct to get the value from the menuItemChoose ?

Answer (score 2):

you can do one more thing if possible,
i have download menu that creates runtime so i have add HashMap and in that HashMap added names.get(i) and download link so it looks like

```
map.put(names.get(i),"link"),
```

now in execute(), i added `Window.open(map.get(menuItem.gettext()),"_blank");`

one more menu i have in my project that is report menu so from database report list is coming and

```
for(final Temp report : listReports){
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(report.getType().toString(), new Command() {
        @Override
                public void execute() {
                    getUiHandlers().showReportPanel(report);
                }
            });
        reportMenuBar.addItem(menuItem);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the benefits of  `UIHandler` Concept to Communicate between the view and presenter.

**Create an interface:**

```
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.UiHandlers;

public interface MyUiHandler extends UiHandlers {
    void onMenuSelected(MenuItem menuitem);
```

}

**Then in your view**

```
public class MyMVPView extends ViewWithUiHandlers<MyUiHandler> implements
        MyMvPPresenter.MyView {
.
.
.
.
```

And **implement that uihandler interface with Presenter**

```
public class MyMvPPresenter
        extends
        Presenter<MyMVPPresenter.MyView, MyMVPPresenter.MyProxy>
        implements MyUiHandler {


//in the same presenter 
public interface MyView extends View, HasUiHandlers<UserDashboardUiHandler> {
    //  

.
.
.
```

Then you will get the override method in presenter like

```
@Override
    public voidonMenuSelected(MenuItem menuitem) {
         //Your implementation here
    }
```

**Usage**

```
@Override           
        public void execute() {

        getUiHandlers().showReportPanel(menuItemChoose );              

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are right vicR, it correct to get the value from the menuItemChoose.
you can do like

```
public void execute() {
    onclickMenu(menuItemChoose);
}

void onclickMenu(MenuItem menuItemChoose){
    if(menuItemChoose.gettext().equals("abc"){
         //call handler method that implemented you in presenter
    }
}
```

Comment: ok makes sense but the menuItemChoose is just inited in this scope so thats not possible or ?!

Comment: it is possible.. i have tried.. I have one more suggestions that may help so please check that.